# Issues with iOS 4.2 (working on 4.1, 4.3 and 4.2.1)

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2, ios4

I have an app that is working fine on my physical device running 4.2.1 iOS.

On the emulator it works fine in 4.1 and 4.3.. however if I try to run the app on the 4.2 emulator, some interface elements (buttons, segmented controllers etc) do not appear, at all.

I have tried changing the build targets to 4.1 and 4.2 to no avail.

I am beyond confused, obviously if I build with a 4.3 target, I can no longer run on my physical device, but if I have it set to 4.2 or 4.1 I can run it on my device running 4.2.1 no problem.  Also if I build with 4.1 as the target I can run it on my 4.1 emulator as well with no problem.  The problem seems purely on the 4.2 iOS emulator.

Is this  a known issue? Is there something I need to worry about?  What, if anything, can I do here?

is the 4.2 emulator just screwed up?

Comment: Can ou add a screenshot of the buttons not working?  And does this problem occurs in a brand new project?

Comment: I will see what I can do about adding screen shots.. Basically the app is a single view 3 3 main regions those regions are:

Comment: a top section that includes an image button a text input field and a round rect button.   The bottom of the screen has a segmented controller and between these two is a mapview.. in 4.1 and 4.3 and my 4.2.1 Device it lays out perfectly.. in iPhone emulator 4.2 and IPad Emulator 4.2 running the app the custom button does not appear at all, nor does the region containing the segemented controller the mapView takes the entire screen under input box and roundrect button

Comment: The project was initially started as a 3.x project I will try a new project with the same xib layout and see what happens

Comment: just an idea, but if your creating the custom button progragramatically, try creating it using interface builder, and vice versa..

Answer (score 1):

Each of the iphone simulator versions keeps its own copies of the app. try deleting the app's directory from `~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/4.2`, it is possible that the nib changed, but isn't being copied in for some reason... do a clean before you build.

Answer (score 0):

I am an app developer of 2 years and I can assure you if it works on the other two builds and not 4.2 the emulator is glitching... This happens alot on my apps but they always work on the phone itself. Apple will still approve your app and it will still load on other people's phones no matter what software version they have (for 4.0 +) 
Don't sweat it ;)